# how to access form data of a POST request with flask

Tags: python, flask

I hope you can help me.
The fact is that I want to implement the transfer of values ​​from the sliders to the image processing function.

[Interface picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNcTd.png)

html code:

```
<form name="uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="test">
                            <div class="slidecontainer">
                                value1
                              <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" name="slider1">
                            </div>
</form>

<img src="{{ url_for('output_photo') }}" width="300" height="300" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
```

I also have an image processing function that runs when the page loads.

```
@app.route('/output_photo')
def output_photo():
    before_img = cv2.imread('images/1.jpg')
    result = before_img.copy()
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(before_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    filtered = cv2.bilateralFilter(imgray, 11, 50, 100)
    output_img = filtered
    retval, buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', output_img)
    response = make_response(buffer.tobytes())
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'

    return response
```

What I need

For example in the filtering method(cv2.bilateralFilter) we have parameters that will need to be changed by the sliders (in this case, it is 11,50,100), but at the same time, this method must have default values ​​so that the image is still processed when the page loads.
How can I that?I will be grateful for the answer

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with those attempts?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I created a function that received data from the sliders, but I can’t pass it to the processing function, and I also don’t know how to make it so that even if the form is not passed, the processing functions have default values

Comment: make sure those sliders map to <input> tags inside the form. then they'll be posted when you submit the form. -- I hope you aren't asking how to access form values in a POST request on the flask side? because that's covered by documentation and tutorials in the very early chapters

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the method with the route and then you can access the form data through request.form.get('#ID_NAME')

You'll need both flask and request from flask when importing too.
So, something like this..

```
@app.route('/edit_img', methods=["POST"])
def edit_img():
    img_id = request.form.get('id')
    ### YOUR CODE
    return render_template(# the page and data your rendering)
```